# How to build multiple html tables with dynamic table IDs in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, recursion, html-table

I am trying to build html tables dynamically in a Style Sheet. I am currently using recursion to build the tables, but I need some type of JavaScript to control the presence of these tables. That is where the table IDs come into play.

Here is my Style Sheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <a href="#" onclick="showtable('test1'); return false;">Hide Table 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showtable('test2'); return false;">Hide Table 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showtable('test3'); return false;">Hide Table 3</a>
    <xsl:call-template name="Recursion">
      <xsl:with-param name="Person" select="0"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="tableID" select="0"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="Recursion">
    <xsl:param name="Person"/>
    <xsl:param name="tableID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Count" select="count(//Table1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Person&lt;$Count">
        <xsl:call-template name="NewTable">
          <xsl:with-param name="Person" select="$Person"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="tableID" select="$tableID+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Person&lt;$Count">
        <xsl:call-template name="Recursion">
          <xsl:with-param name="Person" select="$Person+5"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="NewTable">
    <xsl:param name="Person"/>
    <xsl:param name="tableID"/>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function showHide(id) {

          if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
          }

          else {
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
          }

          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table id="$tableID" border="5">
          <thead>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[1]/*">
              <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(), '_', ' ')"/>
              </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:variable name="Person1" select="$Person+1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Person2" select="$Person+2"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Person3" select="$Person+3"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Person4" select="$Person+4"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Person5" select="$Person+5"/>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[$Person1]/*">
                <xsl:variable name="Attribute" select="position()"/>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[$Person1]/*[$Attribute]"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[$Person2]/*">
                <xsl:variable name="Attribute" select="position()"/>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[$Person2]/*[$Attribute]"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[$Person3]/*">
                <xsl:variable name="Attribute" select="position()"/>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[$Person3]/*[$Attribute]"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[$Person4]/*">
                <xsl:variable name="Attribute" select="position()"/>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[$Person4]/*[$Attribute]"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[$Person5]/*">
                <xsl:variable name="Attribute" select="position()"/>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[$Person5]/*[$Attribute]"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply the Style Sheet, I get the desired results for the tables being built and the number of people in the Style Sheet which is a maximum of 5. The only thing that befuddles me is setting the table IDs to be unique. This current Style Sheet sets the table ID to $tableID literally.

My question is, how do I set a tables ID to equal a variable or at least make every table ID to be unique and be able to track it so that it can be used in the JavaScript method above the table.

Here is the input XML File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Run_Date>2013-12-21</Run_Date>
    <Run_Time>9:30</Run_Time>
    <Date_Ending>2013-12-7</Date_Ending>
    <Invoice_Number>00001</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2013-12-1</Invoice_Date>
    <Due_Date>2013-12-31</Due_Date>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Run_Date>2013-12-21</Run_Date>
    <Run_Time>9:30</Run_Time>
    <Date_Ending>2013-12-7</Date_Ending>
    <Invoice_Number>00001</Invoice_Number>
    <Invoice_Date>2013-12-1</Invoice_Date>
    <Due_Date>2013-12-31</Due_Date>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

And I get this output

```
<Table id="$tableID" border="5">
```

but I want this output

```
<!-- Obviously this is a very dumbed down version of my expected output. I just need the table IDs 
increment by one.-->
<Table id="1" border="5">

<Table id="2" border="5">
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. If you want to, you could give me an idea on how to get the ID to be added to the JavaScript tag dynamically as well, but I should be able to figure that portion out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
 <table id="{$tableID}" b
```

with `{}` so that the Xpath expression in the attribute value is evaluated.

Although the coding is rather inefficient as you are recursing "by hand" and then repeatedly fetching items from the root of the tree

```
/*/*[$Person3]/*">
```

rather than just letting `<xsl:apply-templates/>` naturally apply to each table.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found that <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$tableID"/></xsl:attribute> proved to be useful as well. I didn't even think about doing it in squirlies.